# Laravel: Check for email service provider domain and it subdomain

Tags: php, laravel

I wants restrict user to not to add some popular email service provider domain like gmail.com, yahoo.com, ymail.com, hotmail.com

for that I have created an array

```
$invalidDomain = ['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'ymail.com', 'hotmail.com']
```

and then check user input with in_array

```
if(in_array($insertDomain, $invalidDomain)){
 //restrict
}
```

but now I also want to check for gmail.co.in, hotmail.co.uk

how can I?

Comment: i think you should used this `['gmail', 'yahoo', 'ymail', 'hotmail']`

Comment: okay then I need check for substr right?

Comment: Like, if user input contains any string from array.

Comment: split the `$insertdomain`  using PHP Split function and then used if condition

Comment: example: `$insertDomain = "abc.com"` split into `abc` and then used if condition

Comment: i think you understand my point....

Comment: Yes. Great. Thanks

Comment: your welcome. below i have add my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to achieve this - it will give you more flexibility eg: if you would like to exclude gmail.co.uk but allow gmail.com. See the code snippet below:

```
$insertDomain = "gmail.com";
$invalidDomain = ['gmail\.[a-zA-Z\.]{2,}', 'yahoo\.[a-zA-Z\.]{2,}', 'ymail\.[a-zA-Z\.]{2,}', 'hotmail\.[a-zA-Z\.]{2,}'];

// join regexp
if (preg_match('/^'.implode("$|^", $invalidDomain).'$/', $insertDomain)) {
    // restrict
    echo $insertDomain."\n";
}
```

Comment: wants to exclude gmail.com and gmai.co.uk both

Comment: any further solutions?

Comment: I think the code does what you need. What further solutions would you need?

Comment: I wants to exclude both gmail.com and gmail.co.uk.
your solution allows to go further with gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Used this type of code

```
$invalidDomain = ['gmail', 'yahoo', 'ymail', 'hotmail']
```

and finally in the condition

```
//$insertDomain = "gmail";

    if(in_array($insertDomain, $invalidDomain)){
     //restrict
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP's `parse_url` to determine what domain is being used http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

The output array would contain `host` index that would give you the domain / sub-domain used within the string you pass as an argument to that function .i.e.

```
$partials = parse_url('https://google.com/?id=123');

$insertDomain = $partials['host']; // google.com
```

Comment: parse url return this :-
array:2 [
  "path" => "'https://google.com/"
  "query" => "id=123'"
]

Comment: What exactly are you passing to it as argument?

Comment: It's not the same - my example has protocol in it `https://` and it returns `array(4) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(5) "https"
  ["host"]=>
  string(10) "google.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(1) "/"
  ["query"]=>
  string(6) "id=123"
}
`